# How to flatten an array of dictionaries in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on below problem where I need to flatten array of dicts:

For example- Below is an input:

```
[
    {'a':
        {'b':
            {'c':
                {'d':'e'}
            }
        }
    }, 
    {'a':{'b':{'c':{'d':{'e':'f'}}}}},
    {'a':'b'}
]
```

And the output will be:

```
[
    {'a_b_c_d':'e'}, 
    {'a_b_c_d_e':'f'},
    {'a':'b'}
]
```

Below is what I was able to come up with. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

```
private static List<Map<String, String>> flatDictionary(final List<Map<String, Object>> input) {
    List<Map<String, String>> listHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    if(input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
        return listHolder;
    }
    for(Map<String, Object> mapHolder : input) {
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, String> output = helper(mapHolder, sb, m);
        listHolder.add(output);
    }

    return listHolder;
}

private static Map<String, String> helper(final Map<String, Object> map, final StringBuilder sb, final Map<String, String> output) {
    String mapValue = null;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> holder : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = holder.getKey();
        Object value = holder.getValue();
        if(value instanceof Map) {
            sb.append(key).append("_");
            helper((HashMap<String, Object>) value, sb, output);
        } else if(value instanceof String) {
            sb.append(key);
            mapValue = (String) value;
        }
        output.put(sb.toString(), mapValue);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Better way? So your code works, and you're looking to make it more efficient? Seems more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The code above isn't going to work: The string buffer is being used as a stack of visited key values, with 'append(key)' as an effective equivalent to 'push'.  The problem is that there is no corresponding 'pop', meaning, the string buffer will accumulate too many key values.

Comment: Also, doing a put to output for both the Map and the String cases (of the type of value) seems wrong.  What happens if the value is an empty map?

Comment: I still don't understand why it's not going to work. I am using StringBuilder to populate all the keys for each map.

Answer (score 1):

I would use recursion.

First define a method to flatten a single `Map`

```
public static void flatten(final String keyPrefix, final Map<String, Object> input, final Map<String, Object> output) {
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> e : input.entrySet()) {
        final var key = keyPrefix.isBlank() ? e.getKey() : keyPrefix + "_" + e.getKey();
        if (e.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            // if the nested Map is of the wrong type bad things may happen
            flatten(key, (Map<String, Object>) e.getValue(), output);
        } else {
            output.put(key, e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

NB: This makes no attempt to deal with duplicate keys.

Usage:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final var data = Map.of(
            "A", Map.of("a", "Expect A_a"),
            "B", Map.of("b1", Map.of(
                    "bb1", "expect B_b1_bb1",
                    "bb2", "expect B_b1_bb2"
            )),
            "C", "Expect C");

    final var output = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    flatten("", data, output);

    output.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", k, v));
}
```

Output:

```
C -> Expect C
A_a -> Expect A_a
B_b1_bb2 -> expect B_b1_bb2
B_b1_bb1 -> expect B_b1_bb1
```

---

Now, simply define a method that loops to take your `List`

```
public static final Map<String, Object> flattenAll(final List<Map<String, Object>> input) {
    final var output = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    input.forEach(map -> flatten("", map, output));
    return output;
}
```

NB: This makes no attempt to deal with duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Also is there anything wrong I am doing in my code or my code also does the job? Just making sure because i came up with the solution I have in the interview but interviewer wasn't impressed so not sure what wrong I did.

Comment: Also what is `var` here? I don't think Java as `var`

Comment: @flash what happens with my example? i.e. if there is more than one element at a stage?

Comment: @flash [Java 10](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-10-var-type-inference/). Almost a year ago.

Comment: More than one element meaning? I didnt understand that.. Also I am on Java 7 as of now.

Comment: Java 7 is ancient and unsupported as of years ago! Anyway - just try with my test data - what do you get?